# What is the variable that stores the whole line matching the pattern in sed?

Tags: bash, sed, autohotkey, dvorak

I have a file whose lines are Italian words that end in `[aiou]'`

```
gia'
giacche'
giovedi'
giu'
```

I want to replace these lines with the autohotkey commands that would allow me to write these words with an apostrophe and automatically translate them in their correct versions, that is i want to get

```
::gia'::già
::giacche'::giacché
::giovedi'::giovedì
::giu'::giù
```

I know I can accomplish this with sed, but I couldn't get it to work. I know there is a variable to store the whole line, but I can't find it. If it were `@` the following might work

```
sed -e "s/.a'/::@::@\b\bà/" temp
sed -e "s/.i'/::@::@\b\bì/" temp
sed -e "s/.o'/::@::@\b\bò/" temp
sed -e "s/.u'/::@::@\b\bù/" temp
```

Please note that while the lines are in alphabetical order they DO NOT all start in g, nor there is a pattern in the last two characters of the word.

So do you know what is the variable I'm looking for?
Do you think there is a better solution to my problem than the one I'm trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable you're looking for is `&`. Perhaps something like:

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)a'/::&::\1à/" temp
```

You can also string all of your commands together for all five vowels:

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)a'/::&::\1à/" -e "s/\(.*\)e'/::&::\1é/" -e "s/\(.*\)i'/::&::\1ì/" -e "s/\(.*\)o'/::&::\1ò/" -e "s/\(.*\)u'/::&::\1ù/" temp
```

---

If you have `GNU sed`:

```
sed -re "s/(.+)a'/::&::\1à/" -e "s/(.+)e'/::&::\1é/" -e "s/(.+)i'/::&::\1ì/" -e "s/(.+)o'/::&::\1ò/" -e "s/(.+)u'/::&::\1ù/" temp
```

Comment: I tried with the ampersand but it did not work, because I didn't put there the parenthesis.

What do they mean?
EDIT: uhm, the parenthesis don't seem to matter that match. Still, what about them?

Comment: The parenthesis allow you to group things. For example, the regex: `\(.*\)a` means capture everything up until the `a` and store it in group. This group is called `\1`. Are you using `GNU sed`?

Comment: @FerdinandoRandisi: I've updated the answer with a `GNU sed` solution that works for me. The `-r` flag, enables extended regex (so you don't need to escape the parenthesis, and gives us a few other options, including the ability to match once or more times with the `+` symbol, as opposed to zero or more times with the `*` symbol -- I think this maybe what you're looking for).

Comment: I'm using the sed version built in Cygwin, i think it's the regular one.

Thank you much!

At present it does not work because I need to find an encoding that bash likes while at the same time supporting accented letters, but the sed problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1{x;s/^/aàeéiìoòuù/;x};/[aeiou]'\''$/!b;G;s/((.*)(.).)\n.*\3(.).*/::\1::\2\4/' file
```

Explanation:

- `1{x;s/^/aàeéiìoòuù/;x}` store a lookup table in the hold space (HS) at the beginning of the file
- `/[aeiou]'\''$/!b` bail out unless the desired word ending
- `G` append a newline and the contents of the HS to the pattern space (PS)
- `s/((.*)(.).)\n.*\3(.).*/::\1::\2\4/` use the last but one character in the original word as a lookup in the appended lookup table and generate the required output